# HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync throws when charset is surrounded by quotes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to POST files containing arbitrary binary data to a WebAPI 2 controller as multipart/form-data.

When trying to read the files using the following:

```
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadDirectoryPath);

await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The character set provided in ContentType is invalid. 
Cannot read content as string using an invalid character set. 
---> System.ArgumentException: '"utf-8"' is not a supported encoding name. 
For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
Parameter name: name
```

I understand that the problem is the quotes around utf-8 and it is [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790174/system-net-http-httpcontent-readasstringasync-does-not-handle-imperfect-content-type-headers) bug in `HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()` used internally as explained [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5014).

The request is being sent from a Unity3D app and I am unable to change the charset in the request body.

Here is the code I am using in the Unity3D script to create the POST request.

```
WWW chunkFile = new WWW("file:///" + Path.Combine(tempZipFolderPath, chunkFilenames[j]));

yield return chunkFile;

if (chunkFile.error != null)
    throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} error opening file {1}", chunkFile.error, chunkFilenames[j]));

//BUGFIX: Not using IMultipartFormSection because of https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?826626_htlchp13nh8th2to

var form = new WWWForm();

form.AddField("chunkNumber", chunkNumber);
form.AddField("totalChunks", totalChunks);
form.AddField("identifier", tempZipFileName);
form.AddBinaryData("filename", chunkFile.bytes, chunkFilenames[j]);

var scanUploadPostRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(WebApiScanUploadUrl, form);

yield return scanUploadPostRequest.Send();

//BUGBUG: charset UTF-8 wrapped in quotes causes error
```

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Maybe you should post the code you use on Unity3D side too...

Comment: @Programmer I've added the relevant Unity3D code to the question.

Comment: Can't really find anything wrong here. I noticed that you used multipart on the server side, why not use the-same thing from the client side. This can be done with the `UnityWebRequest Post(string uri, List<IMultipartFormSection> multipartFormSections)` function overload.

Comment: @Programmer Because of this bug: https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?826626_htlchp13nh8th2to It's like I've hit all the bugs that exist out there. In any case form.AddBinaryData turns it into multipart.

Comment: Have you tried doing something like `form.headers["Content-Type"] = "utf-8";`?

Comment: @dharms Tried it but doesn't work. I think that in a multipart message each part sets its own content type which is read when that part is being read. Basically each uploaded file can have it's own charset I think.

Comment: @NVM:  I haven't tried multipart forms, but I posted a workaround for the basic ReadAsStringAsync [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820288/how-to-accept-a-charset-containing-quotes) that you might be able to adapt.